# Where to save Azure Cloud Storage Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I builded a REST-API which uploads images to my azure storage container. My azure storage container is secured an access key, which I use in my POST method like this:

```
 StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("[storage]", "[key]");
```

Now I want to deploy my service to the azure cloud - but I dont know how to manage the security issue with my plain written access key in the POST method.

> Where should I save sensitive data like this? Or are my worries wrong
>   and this is not an issue?

Info:
The REST-API is a ASP.NET Web API Project

Comment: If you are using azure, simple you can store any sensitive data in azure key vault. Also you can enable managed identity for your api and add it to the storage access control. I recommend this because you don’t need to manage your secrets. The below links are from azure docs. Let me know know if u need help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Azure portal => your web app => Configuration => Application Settings
```

That is the simplest.

You can also use a keyvault, but the application settings are the easiest by far, and perfectly fine for this case.

> For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core developers, setting app settings in App
>   Service are like setting them in  in Web.config or
>   appsettings.json, but the values in App Service override the ones in
>   Web.config or appsettings.json

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/configure-common

[image]